# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' while creating object of model class

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zend framework. 
I have created Users.php in the model folder.
The code of the model folder is as following.

```
<?php
include("Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php");
include("Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php");
    class users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
        protected $_name = 'users';
        protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_DbTable_User';

        public function fetchUsers() {
            $select = $this->select();
            //$select->where('completed = 0');
            $select->order(array('date_created DESC', 'user_id ASC'));
            return $this->fetchAll($select);
        }
        public function insert_user1(array $data) {
            echo "called";
        }
    }

    class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
        public function insert_user(array $data) {
        print_r($data);
        //$obj = new users();
        }   
    }
?>
```

I have created a form and from the controller I am passing the data getting from the form to the model so that the model then inserts that data in database.

But if I try to create object of the users class It generated an fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)
```

And if If I try to create an Application_Model_DbTable_User class, It works fine and When I call the method of that class, It also works fine but then when I want to insert the data to the database it then generates the fatal error as mentioned above.

Here is my controller code.

```
$data = array('first_name' => $request->getParam('first_name'),
              'last_name' => $request->getParam('last_name'),
                            'country' => $request->getParam('country'),
                            'address' => $request->getParam('address'),
                            'username' => $request->getParam('user_name'),
                            'password' => $request->getParam('password'),
                            'password' => $request->getParam('address'),
                            'date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
              );
            //$tasksGateway = new users();

            $obj = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
            $obj->insert_user($data);
```

Here is the exact error:

```
exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for users' in C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php:755 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(739): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupDatabaseAdapter() #1 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(268): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setup() #2 C:\wamp\www\alancer\application\models\DBTable\Users.php(22): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->__construct() #3 C:\wamp\www\alancer\application\controllers\UserController.php(55): Application_Model_DbTable_User->insert_user(Array) #4 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): UserController->processAction() #5 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('processAction') #6 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #7 C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(212): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #8 C:\wamp\www\alancer\web_root\index.php(35): Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/...') #9 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have deleted `ErrorController.php` or not have created it in first place inside your default module . Now what is happing is some application error is occuring hence ZF is shifting controller to `ErrorController.php` but since it do not exist you are getting such fatal error.

Error Controller should contain

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
            $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
            return;
        }

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);

                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);

                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }



        // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
            $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }




}
```

Update

You cannot create instance of classes which extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract directly instead you should use table object to do so 
for e.g

```
$user = new  Users();
$user->createRow()->insert_user($data);
```

Instead of

```
$obj = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
            $obj->insert_user($data);
```

Comment: yes. I did not create ErrorController.php. But what should I code in this file?

Comment: What files should I include in ErrorController.php? Because it now gives me the error of `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in C:\wamp\www\alancer\application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 26`

Comment: @Ahmad updated my ErrorController code now copy it and test it.

Comment: Getting the same error. But I print the $errors object and I found the  the error `Zend_Db_Table_Exception: No adapter found for users in C:\wamp\www\alancer\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line <i>755</i>`. So now what is the problem in my model code?

Comment: @Ahmad again updated the code check it should now show the same error which you print it by default .

Comment: I have updated my question and post the error. Now please help me how to solve my problem?

Comment: I used your code but now the error is `Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for users`